# Extraer valores de una lista a partir de otra por medio de sus índices

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparaciones

Necesito "cortar" un vector con los datos que son útiles de los que no lo son a partir de otro vector, es decir, quiero crear otro vector con los datos útiles pero los datos útiles los determinará otro vector.

Por ejemplo:

```
a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,0,0]

b=[31, 42, 42, 100, 22, 21, 34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12 ,14, 21, 19, 100]
```

De estos vectores quiero obtener un tercero de la forma:

```
c= [34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12, 14]
```

En este caso los ceros de la lista "a" indican los valores que no son útiles de la lista "b" (b tiene un dato más que a)

Comment: Hola Manuel, bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Has intentado algo? Deberias agregar lo que has intentado y explicar que no te funciona. Por otro lado, supongo que son válidos aquellos items de b para los que en el mismo índice de a hay un entero mayor de 0 (o que no tiene un índice válido en a). Si es así, ¿por qué es válido el 21? ¿No debería ser el 100?

Comment: Hola gracias por la bienvenida, la respuesta que me dio J. Ruiz es la que buscaba, incluso me he equivocado al formular la pregunta. Lo que necesito es extraer los datos de a que son distintos a cero que coincidan con los datos de la lista b, no sé si con eso queda más claro.

Comment: Tienes razón, la lista "c" debería ser `[34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12, 14]` por eso me he equivocado ahorita edito la lista "a" para que concuerde, no importa si son de distinta longitud lo que quiero recuperar son los valores que coinciden para aquellos números distintos a cero en los índices de la lista "b"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que en el momento en el que una lista sea mayor que la otra, los índices de más en la lista mayor no nos interesan, el built-in [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip) es perfecto para esto.

`zip` retorna un iterador que permite iterar paralelamente sobre varios iterables retornando para cada índice una tupla con los valores de todos los iterables para esa posición.

```
for pareja in zip([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]):
    print(pareja)
```

> ```
> (1, 4)
> (2, 5)
> (3, 6)
> ```

Para hacer lo que deseas, solo necesitamos `zip` y un condicional. Usando una lista por compresión:

```
a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
b = [31, 42, 42, 100, 22, 21, 34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12 ,14, 21, 19, 100]
c = [b_item for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b) if a_item]
```

usar `zip` es una forma genérica de hacer esto, que va a funcionar sea cual sea la condición.

Para aplicar un filtro booleano sobre un iterable usando otro iterable de boleanos tenemos a nuestra disposición [`itertoools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress) en la stdlib. En nuestro caso `a` no es una lista de boleanos, pero dado que Python evalúa un entero como `False` si es 0 y `True` en cualquier otro caso, podemos aplicarlo en nuestro caso:

```
import itertools


a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 0]
b = [31, 42, 42, 100, 22, 21, 34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12 ,14, 21, 19, 100]    
c = list(itertools.compress(b, a))
```

Comment: Gracias FJSevilla, no pensé que fuera algo tan sencillo, me han ayudado bastante!

Answer (score 0):

En este caso se resolvería con una sola línea de la siguiente manera:

```
a=[0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,5,7,8,0,0]

b=[31, 42, 42, 100, 22, 21, 34, 56, 89, 43, 2, 12 ,14, 21, 19, 100]

c = [b[i] for i in range(0,len(a)) if a[i]!=0]
```

La lista "c" estará formada por todos los elementos de la lista "b" que estén en los indices para los cuales la lista "a" tenga un valor diferente de 0.

Comment: Exactamente esto es lo que buscaba, aún soy muy novato con Python y lo estaba intentando como si estuviera programando en C o Matlab, gracias!

Comment: Es normal, yo también tengo el python oxidado y en cada lenguaje se accede a los elementos de una manera... Me alegro de que te haya servido.